# How can I retrieve the input data in the class Lighthouse that is stored in Array employeeList?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Lighthouse
    Public ProductID As String
    Public Firstname As String
    Public Lastname As String
    Public Gender As String
    Public Birthdate As String
    Public Contact As Integer
    Public Email As String
    Public Address As String
    Public SSS As String
    Public TIN As String
    Public Philhealth As String
    Public Position As Integer
End Class

Private employeeList As List(Of Lighthouse) = New List(Of Lighthouse)
```

Let say I already have the value for the objects in Lighthouse, How can I retrieve the Value that I input? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but maybe you want to do `Dim lh As New Lighthouse() : lh.ProductID = "something" ... : employeeList.Add(lh)`?

Comment: You should declare public **properties** instead of public **fields**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seaching this?

```
Sub load()
    Dim item = New Lighthouse With {
      .Firstname = "Chris",
      .Lastname = "Berlin",
   [....]
    }

    employeeList.Add(item)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access items in you list in several ways. When you retrieve an item, all the properties and methods of you class are available from that item.

You can loop through each item in the class and display the properties for each item.

You can set the `DataSource` of a `ListBox` to the list. `Items` in a `ListBox` are `Object`s but you cast them back to the underlying type to be able to access their properties. I added a `.ToString` method to your class so the `ListBox` will know what to display.

```
Public Class Lighthouse
    Public ProductID As String
    Public Firstname As String
    Public Lastname As String
    Public Gender As String
    Public Birthdate As String
    Public Contact As Integer
    Public Email As String
    Public Address As String
    Public SSS As String
    Public TIN As String
    Public Philhealth As String
    Public Position As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Lastname}, {Firstname}"
    End Function
End Class

Private employeeList As List(Of Lighthouse) = New List(Of Lighthouse)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Access by Index
    Dim index = 2
    Dim LH = employeeList(index) 'Returns the third item in the list
    MessageBox.Show(LH.Lastname)
    'Loop through each item a
    For Each emp As Lighthouse In employeeList
        MessageBox.Show($"{emp.Firstname} {emp.Lastname}")
    Next
    'Access from a ListBox
    ListBox1.DataSource = employeeList
    Dim LHemp = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Lighthouse)
    TextBox1.Text = LHemp.Email
End Sub
```

As a side note... Please type anything that is a date `As Date`. This will save you trouble in the future.